# Deploy a Django project with virtualenv to GAE using pycharm, or anything

Tags: django, google-app-engine, virtualenv, pycharm

I know how to start a Django project with virtualenv in PyCharm.
I know how to start a Django project with app engine support in PyCharm.
I know how to deploy a project GAE in PyCharm.

But I cannot successfully deploy a Django project with virtualenv to GAE using Pycharm. Please Help.

Comment: Are there any specific errors that you're getting or are you unsure on how to push to GAE using pycharm?

Comment: deployed to GAE using built-in utilities, but the virtualenv does not seem to be deployed. I was deploying a pinax project

Comment: Unfortunately, virtual environments are not currently transferable according to their official page see link `http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#making-environments-relocatable`. They are working on that though. If you'd like to deploy your project and run it within a virtual environment there is a pretty useful guide on how to do it written by Michal Karzynski `http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/`.